# Mapping Fn + W|A|S|D to arrow keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tried using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to map <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) to arrow keys, but didn't find any working solution.

I need them to work with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> so I can easily select/highlight text with just the left hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ukelele or keylayout files can't be used to remap fn, but KeyRemap4MacBook can, at least on my Apple Wireless Keyboard. Try using a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: This was just the thing I was looking for! Works greatly :). Code seems simple also. I just didn't realise how to use ModifierFlag